# Fitting a truncated lognormal distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution, data-fitting

Referring to the subject:

[Fitting a lognormal distribution to truncated data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947799/fitting-a-lognormal-distribution-to-truncated-data-in-r?rq=1)

I am trying to estimate parameters of a truncated lognormal distribution:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(truncdist)


D <- rlnorm(1000,meanlog = -0.75, sdlog = 1.5)
# Censor data #
min <- 0.10
max <- 20
Dt <- D[D > min]
Dt <- Dt[Dt <= max]

#fitt <- fitdist(Dt, "lognormal", lower = min, upper = max)

dtruncated_log_normal <- function(x, meanlog, sdlog) 
  dtrunc(x, "lnorm", a=.10, b=20, meanlog=meanlog, sdlog=sdlog)
ptruncated_log_normal <- function(x, meanlog, sdlog) 
  ptrunc(x, "lnorm", a=.10, b=20, meanlog=meanlog, sdlog=sdlog)

fitdist(Dt, "truncated_log_normal", start = c(meanlog=0, sdlog=1))
```

But I get the below error:

```
Error in manageparam(start.arg = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,  : 
  Wrong type of argument for start
```

Where is the problem?  It is about the initial values. But I can't solve it.

I will be very glad for any help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, according to the documentation `fitdist` expects start to be a named list and you are passing in a named vector. Does using `start = list(meanlog=0, sdlog=1)` work, or at least give a different error message?

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks a lot. It worked. If you answer, I will submit it. Thanks a gain.